# Turn off DMARC report for pass

Tags: dmarc

I would like to receive reports only for DMARC quarantined mail and failures, but I still receive mails for every successful e-mail that has been sent from my server.

Configuration in dns looks like this

```
v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:XXXXXXX
```

Is there any way to stop receiving reports without quarantine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, such configuration is only available for the (now mostly defunct) *forensic* reports, for the *agggregate* reports (`rua`) you can only take what you can get.

Instead of looking for a way for people to send you *less data*, **consider using one of the commercially available DMARC processing software or services** to have your data *parsed & visualized* to better showcase the interesting data.

XML was never that good for human consumptions anyway. And after some short implementation phase where you look at aggregated tables, you should *prefer* to only receive a notification when something important was reported, likely not even on *most* reports referring to *quarantine* decisions.

Comment: examples of DMARC processing services in no particular order: [dmarcian](https://dmarcian.com/dmarc-saas-platform/), [report-uri](https://report-uri.com/products/dmarc_monitoring), [uriports](https://www.uriports.com/dmarc)

Comment: oh and if you want to dispute my *"not good for human consumption"* claim, there is also a really neat XSLT file to view dmarc reports floating around somewhere.

Comment: Poking around for XSLT files, I found [this nice one](https://www.tana.it/sw/dmarc-xsl/) and [this somewhat simpler one](https://gist.github.com/alexproca/b6ff736c6d7b1e0fa3a2a4d97a19a8e4). Dmarcian also wants you to know that they have [an online converter](https://dmarcian.com/xml-to-human-converter/) that they hope will convince you to sign up.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is "failure reports." Failure reports are not the aggregate reports (`rua`) but are the `ruf=mailto:dmarc-ruf@example.com` reports, often referred to as the forensic reports.

Here's an excerpt from DMARC.org's FAQ:

> ### [Do I want to receive Failure Reports (ruf=)?](https://dmarc.org/wiki/FAQ#Do_I_want_to_receive_Failure_Reports_.28ruf.3D.29.3F)
>
> Failure reports are very useful for forensic analysis to help identify
> both bugs in your own mail sending software and some kinds of phishing
> or other impersonation attacks, but... a failure report is sent
> immediately, *every time* a receiver rejects a message due to your DMARC
> policy. The receiver may even send a report if the mail is accepted
> but one of the authentication mechanism does not pass the alignment
> test. A forensic report can be a complete copy of the rejected email
> in Abuse Reporting Format (ARF). You may think your sending practices
> are good, and there should be few emails rejected, but **every email
> that spoofs your domain will be rejected too and you are asking to get
> a copy.** This could be several times the volume of your legitimate
> emails. So no, you do not want to receive Failure Reports until you
> are well prepared for them.